# How to correctly apply MYSQL mode to the H2 database? SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, h2

I try to use the `WITH` statement in my SQL query via H2 database on the test layer, but I receive  the error:

> SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement

- I simplified the query for clear understanding:

  WITH cte as (SELECT * from personal_best LIMIT 1) SELECT * FROM cte;

This query works well from the dev stage via MYSQL8:

```java
 @Query(nativeQuery = true,
            value = "WITH cte as (SELECT * from personal_best LIMIT 1) SELECT * FROM cte")
    PersonalBest getLastByExerciseAndRepeats();
```

But I can't use such functionality on the `test` stage, where I use `H2`.

application.properties (test):

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;MODE=MYSQL
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.data.jpa.repositories.bootstrap-mode=default
spring.h2.console.enabled=true

spring.h2.console.settings.web-allow-others=true
spring.datasource.generate-unique-name = false 
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console/
...
```

So, does exist the way to use needed functionality via `H2`?

Comment: I searched the H2 SQL grammar documentation but as far as I can tell, it doesn't implement common table expressions. Do you have some reason to think H2 supports CTE syntax?

Comment: Many CTE queries can be rewritten as `SELECT ... FROM (SELECT ...) AS t`. Often you don't need to use a CTE except for recursive queries or if you reference the CTE more than once in the outer query.

Comment: @BillKarwin, thanks. I thought the MYSQL mode can give such opportunity. It seems it isn't. So I'll follow your tip and will avoid such syntaxis

Comment: You need to provide a real query and complete stack trace of exception. `WITH cte as (SELECT * from personal_best LIMIT 1) SELECT * FROM cte` is valid for H2.

Comment: @EvgenijRyazanov let it be a real query. `WITH cte as (SELECT * from personal_best LIMIT 1) SELECT * FROM cte` also throws exception

Comment: You need to provide full information about this exception, `Caused by:` part in the stack trace should contain original error from database.